# How do I get my register-function to auto-login (HTML, Flask, Python)

Tags: authentication

I've tried to add `session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]` right before my `return redirect("/")` line but I'm getting a error when I try that: `IndexError: list index out of range`.

This is the code I for my register function:

```
    @app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""

     # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        # Ensure confirmed password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("confirm password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

         # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))

        # Ensure username is not already used
        if len(rows) == 1:
            return apology("username already taken", 403)

        # Ensure passwords are the same
        elif request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirm password"):
            return apology("these passwords do not match", 403)

        # Store name and hashed password
        name = request.form.get("username")
        hash = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))

        # Put name and password into database
        db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (:name, :hash)", name=name, hash=hash)

        # Return user to index page
        """TODO: Add message for succesfully registering"""

        return redirect("/")

        # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IndexError: list index out of range` error is because `rows` is an empty `list`. (Empty because the database was queried before the user was registered).

Query the database after the user is registered to get their `id`. Then, add that `id` to the Flask session before redirecting to `"/"`.

```py
# ... (the rest of your code here)

# Return user to index page
"""TODO: Add message for successfully registering"""

# Query database for id
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))

# Add the user id to the Flask session
session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

return redirect("/")
```